# getent hosts not using DNS

Tags: ubuntu, openldap, nsswitch, getent

I'm using Ubuntu workstation (14.04), using OpenLDAP for authentication.  The `/etc/nsswitch.conf` files on these look like this so that to get a host it should try files, then LDAP and then go on to check DNS:

```
passwd:         files ldap
group:          files ldap
shadow:         files ldap
hosts:          files ldap dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
networks:       files ldap
protocols:      files ldap
services:       files ldap
ethers:         files ldap
rpc:            files ldap
netgroup:       ldap
aliases:        ldap
```

Most of my hosts on our network are just defined in our DNS, which works fine using `nslookup`, but `getent hosts` only returns entries defined within LDAP or files.